# Why are all these answers not answering the actual question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, answers

I just stumbled across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20498831/refused-to-display-in-a-frame-because-it-set-x-frame-options-to-sameorigin) from 2013 about an error message received when trying to authenticate with Google in iPhone Safari. The error message mentions iFrames. The author self answered it 2 days later and the issue seemed to be settled.

The question has since gathered 19 more answers, most of which do not answer the specific question. Most of them talk about embedding a YouTube video in the page, which is not what the OP was asking about.

This raises the following questions for me:

1. How did this happen? Was there a merge between similar questions, or are people just googling the error message and answering the question based on the title alone?
2. What should be done about this? Should the question be edited to be more generic, so the answers make sense? Or should the answers be deleted / downvoted / flagged?
3. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Its probably not a merge since that would show in the revision history (Question was asked in 2013 which is after merges were improved). What I assume might have happened is duplicate closures, maybe someone asked about errors they were getting when embedding YouTube videos and their question got closed as a duplicate of this and people posted the answer to this question and then other people probably got directed to it from search engines and kept adding more answers related to YouTube, etc.

Comment: How it happens is nobody downvoting obviously bad answers to a question. How the question got attention, and if it should have gotten attention, is up for debate.

Comment: It looks like the answerers were lazy and meant to find this more related, and similarly titled post: [Embed YouTube video - Refused to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661182). That said, most of the answers are don't add anything new and should be deleted. There are also a striking number of effectively duplicate posts (that haven't been closed) on the topic, many of which have similar irrelevant youtube answers.

Comment: Probably because the underlying problem is effectively the same, but the OP's solution is specific to the service they are using while all the other answers are specific to the service the answerers are using. On some level... this question, and teh problems being solved within it's answers, are hardly programming related... they're not using the service they are using correctly.

Comment: "Why are all these answers not answering the actual question?" Welcome to the difficulties of content curation on Stack Overflow... :-)

Comment: I agree with others that it's the lack of downvotes, but would point out that very few viewers these days bother to upvote good answers even though there's essentially no cost other than a second or two of their time. If they're not willing to put in the effort to upvote answers when there's no cost, why would you expect them to downvote when doing so reduces your own rep?

Comment: @pjs any proof of that statement, or just your own personal observations which you are presenting as a fact?